# Convert a iOS formatted timeto php timestamp

Tags: ios, time

I have a string as "18 Jul 2014 11 59 PM". How to convert it to php timestamp format like 1404728913? Thanks in advance….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSDateFormatter to convert `date` in to `UTC` timestamp

```
NSString *str          =   @"18 Jul 2014 11 59 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter  =   [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy hh mm a"];
NSDate *yourDate                =   [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"%@",@([yourDate timeIntervalSince1970]));
```

Give output 1405708140 which is UTC timstamp

Answer (score 0):

Add a : between the hour and minute and strtotime can read it.
Something like this:

```
$timestamp = strtotime(preg_replace('/(.+)([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2})/','$1$2:$3',$string));
```